# Explicitly providing "user_id" to Revisionable

Tags: laravel, revisionable

My company uses a 3 tiered system for our web application:

1. **Front end** - client layer
2. **Middle layer** (composes requests, provides validation and authentication) - accessible by the front end
3. **Backend** (where all the database requests are made) - not accessible by the front end

In addition we have a SOA architecture which separates parts of our application. For example, the accounts API is completely separate from the Ads API (which is *my* primary focus). This means that I don't have a User model available to me in the backend API.

Is it possible to explicitly provide a "user_id" to Revisionable instead of relying on some sort of foreign key or implicitly retrieved user id?

The idea would be that a request to retrieve history for an edited record would simply return the provided user_id. We would then merge that with a request against our Accounts API to determine who the actual user was.

We're using Lumen 8.x for middle and back end layers.

Comment: You can handle event broadcast to all activities in single place where to easily identified.